# Quotes in Quotes in Quotes in a "Linux" Shell

Tags: linux, shell, syntax, quotes

Let's say I have shell programs a,b,c, each one executing a command from the other one. For some reasons, I need quotes. Example:

```
a 'b 'c 'echo test'''
```

So a shall call b, which shall call c, which will call 'echo test'. You already see that my quotes will be wrong interpreted. Also, note that a, b, and c are C-programs calling system().

Is there any solution to do that, preserving the quotes?

Comment: Where? In the C-Program? How do you mean that?

Comment: As written above, the shell scripts are, in reality, C-Programs calling system(), which only *behaves like* a shell script.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that. So `$()` didn't work?

Comment: Np, but I have no idea where I could apply $(). Could you please make an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no ready solution for C, but in this case, it is advisable to take your string-to-be-quoted, replace every `'` with `'\''` and enclose the whole stuff in `'`.

1. The innermost part is `echo test` That can happily be put in `''` and given to `c`: `c 'echo test'`.
2. Then you want to give that string to `b`. Here it starts, because the said string contains `'`s, so you do `'` + `c '\''echo test'\''` + `'` which you give to b: `b 'c '\''echo test'\'''`.
   What happens here? You have concatenated several concatenated parts for `b`'s argument:

   1. `'c ', which becomes just`c `,
   2. `\'`, which becomes `'`
   3. `'echo test'`, which is `echo test` after stripping the quotes,
   4. `\'` again -> `'`, and
   5. `''` which is nothing and only exists because there is a `'` at the end of the original string. It can be omitted if processed manually, but isn't worth the effort in an algorithm.

   So you get `c 'echo test'` after dequoting that, which shows that the said algorithm should work.
3. Now you do this process to `b 'c '\''echo test'\'''` again in order to have an argument for `a`: so you'll get `a 'b '\''c '\''\'\'''\''echo test'\''\'\'''\'''\'''`.
4. Even trickier: you now want to put that in a C string, so you'll have to double the `\`s: `system("a 'b '\\''c '\\''\\'\\'''\\''echo test'\\''\\'\\'''\\'''\\'''");`.

If you do the said optimization on starting, ending and successive `'`s, you get

```
b 'c '\''echo test'\'
```

and

```
a 'b '\''c '\''\'\'\''echo test'\''\'\'
```

resp.

```
system("a 'b '\\''c '\\''\\'\\'\\''echo test'\\''\\'\\'");
```

.

Alternatively, you could work without the `'` and just quote the spaces and the '\'s, but that would probably even trickier...

Let me try:

1. c: `echo test` -> `echo\ test` -> `c echo\ test`.
2. b: `b c\ echo\\\ test`.
3. a: `a b\ c\\\ echo\\\\\\\ test`.
4. system: `system("a b\\ c\\\\\\ echo\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ test")`.

Quote ugly, but it works.

Tested with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

import subprocess
sp=subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in sp.stdout:
    print "%s> %s" % (sys.argv[0], line),
exit(sp.wait())
```

as `a`, `b` and `c` and

```
import os
print 1
os.system("a 'b '\\''c '\\''\\'\\'''\\''echo test'\\''\\'\\'''\\'''\\'''")
print 2
os.system("a 'b '\\''c '\\''\\'\\'\\''echo test'\\''\\'\\'")
print 3
os.system("a b\\ c\\\\\\ echo\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ test")
```

as `test.py` and called with

```
PATH=.:$PATH python -m test
```

As python has in this case the same quoting rules as C, it is a sufficient test.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting it! Works as well, though the solution with double quotes looks more "readable" :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the inner quotes. Unfortunately it's not really possible for single-quotes, so I'd use double-quotes for all the outer levels and single-quotes for the innermost quotes, because double-quoted string can contain single-quotes without escaping. So the result should be:

```
a "b \"c 'echo test'\""
```

Note, that you need to add backslashes for each level you need to pass through, so if " were used at the last level, you'd need

```
a "b \"c \\\"echo test\\\"\""
```

and next level would get to 7 backslashes and so on.